# Is there other way to get your DISPLAY env without using shell?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a script that will get executed by incrond when it sees changes in a watch dir. There is only a few env vars that are available in the script, the rest get cleared by incrond. So this becomes a problem when you want to execute something that depends on X vars such as $DISPLAY. So I'm wondering if it's possible to get var $DISPLAY from inside the script without querying from user shell

Answer (score 2):

To get a environment variable of a running process, you need to look at the `environ` file in the `proc` filesystem. In your case it's:

```
user@host:~$ strings /proc/$(pidof -s Xorg)/environ
XORGCONFIG=/etc/X11/xorg.conf
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
LANG=de_CH.UTF-8
DISPLAY==:0
TERM=linux
PWD=/
UPSTART_JOB=gdm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

using systemd login manager (a bit slow):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

user=bac0n

# Cannot find how multiple session is presented.
session=($(loginctl show-user --value -p Sessions $user))

# Get display from the first array element.
display=$(loginctl show-session --value -p Display $session)

echo $display
```